# Iphone variable is loading syntax it seems and not the variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, variables

I'm assigning a variable string from an XML node and for some reason when i'm using it later i'm getting it read like this:

**edit**
The Current URL to parse is a NSLog that is written when the page is loaded from the [loadXML currentCat]]

**NSLog:**

```
 Current URL To Parse: <UILongPressGestureRecognizer: 0x677c240; state = Possible; view = <UITableViewCellContentView 0x67780b0>; target= <(action=_longPressGestureRecognized:, target=<UITableViewCell 0x677c340>)
```

**tempFullUrl being set** - this is in my class.h

```
@interface PromotionViewController : UITableViewController {

    NSString *tempFullUrl;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *tempFullUrl;

@end
```

It's also synthasised in the .m

**Var being Set:**

```
        NSArray *urlArray = [item elementsForName:kName_url];
        for(CXMLElement *url in urlArray) 
        {
            newobj.urlSearch = url.stringValue;
            tempFullUrl = url.stringValue;
            NSLog(@"Temp Full URL: : %@", tempFullUrl);

            [url release];
            [kName_url release];
        }


        [totalArray addObject:newobj];

    }}
```

**Var being used:**

```
else if(currentType == @"p2FullSearch") {


        NSString *searchType = @"categorySearch";

        PromotionViewController *loadXML = [[PromotionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PromotionViewController" bundle:nil];
        [loadXML setCurrentCat: tempFullUrl];
        [loadXML setCurrentType: searchType];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:loadXML animated:YES];

    }
```

The app falls over, highlighting the `tempFullUrl = url.stringValue;` line but doesn't say why! I assume as the var tempFullUrl is being set weirdly

Any help would be appreciated

Tom

Comment: Show us more, like the tempFullUrl declaration.

Comment: can you modify your original question to show what `tempFullUrl` is declared as? It should be `NSString *` and not `NSURL *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going through your synthesised accessor, so the string is getting released. Use

```
self.tempFullURL =
```

Instead of assigning to the ivar directly. In your case it looks like the area of memory has been reassigned to a gesture recogniser which is showing up in your log statements.

Comment: Thanks that worked. One thing i've just noticed though, it's assigned the URL the value of the final result rather than the selected one - Do yo have any idea of what i'm doing wrong there?